# Error: Al hacer una columna específica no editable en DataDridView, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid, visual-studio-2010

Tengo el siguiente `DataGridView` del cual solo debo permitir seleccionar **un valor a la vez**, si el usuario selecciona un valor, la columna de selección debe quedar `ReadOnly` si el usuario desmarca el valor que seleccionó, habilitar la columna de selección `ReadOnly == false` para poder seleccionar otra opción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En el evento `CellValueChanged` del DataGridView tengo lo siguiente:**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value) == true)
        //if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) == true)
        {
              dataGridView1.Columns["columna_seleccion"].ReadOnly = true;
              //dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
              //dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = true;
        }
        else
        {
              dataGridView1.Columns["columna_seleccion"].ReadOnly = false;
              //dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = false;
              //dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = false;
        }
   }
}
```

> Al momento de seleccionar el valor, en esta linea: `dataGridView1.Columns["columna_seleccion"].ReadOnly = true;` muesta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?**

**Entorno:** Visual Studio 2010, C# (WindowsForms) & .NET NetFramework 4.

Comment: ¿Si lo que quieres es que únicamente se pueda marcar una fila por qué no haces que al marcar una fila se desmarquen las demás? Sería más sencillo y me parece más usable.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva Entonces tendría que recorrer nuevamente el `DataGridView` y desmarcar las demás opciones Cierto?.

Comment: O comprobar si alguna está marcada (como mucho debería haber una) y desmarcarla

Comment: @AsierVillanueva  Se me ocurre algo como esto: ` foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0].Value) == true)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }`  o me sugiere algún ejemplo en código?, por favor.

Comment: En realidad la condición del primer `if` no tendría mucho sentido. Te he dejado un ejemplo como respuesta que creo que se entenderá mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de deshabilitar la columna lo que puedes hacer es desmarcar el check del resto de las filas cuando se marque una. De esta forma sólo podrás tener una marcada.

El código podría ser algo así:

```
private void dataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   // Compruebas que se trate de la columna (doy por hecho que es la de índice 0)
   if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
   {
      // Comprobamos si el usuario ha marcado o desmarcado la casilla
      var isChecked = (bool)dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
      // Si la ha marcado desmarcamos el todas las filas excepto la actual
      if (isChecked)
      {
         foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
         {
            if (row.Index != e.RowIndex)
            {
               row.Cells[0].Value = false;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Esto no va a ejecutar el cellvaluechanged recursivamente tambien?

Comment: Lo he escrito sobre la marcha y no he podido probarlo pero únicamente debería lanzar el evento si cambia el valor (como mucho puede haber una fila marcada con lo que únicamente lanzaría uno) y al estar desmarcando la celda comprobaría que `isChecked` es `false` y saldría.

Comment: Por alguna razón la linea `var isChecked = (bool)dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;` da el siguiente error: `Specified cast is not valid.` , lo he solucionad usando `Convert.ToBoolean(...)` , Gracias por su tiempo @AsierVillanueva